# Website loads blocky

Tags: html, css

I published my first website ([www.dirkwolthuis.nl](http://www.dirkwolthuis.nl/)). It is a one page website with a lot of images and elements. In chrome on my mac it loads fine and scrolls okay. On a iPad or iPhone the elements tend to render more slowly than the user scroll. Is this a common problem with one page websites? And can I do something about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page load shouldn't be that much of a problem. But some of the images are quite large, especially the ones being served up for your article images, some of these images are over 1000px wide but only being used at 450px or less.

As these are CSS background images this can easily be dealt with the aid of media queries.

For instance:

```
.article-card.privacy {
    url(/images/articles/whatsapp-small.jpg);
}

@media (min-width: 720px) {
    .article-card.privacy {
        url(/images/articles/whatsapp-medium.jpg);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
    .article-card.privacy {
        url(/images/articles/whatsapp-large.jpg);
    }
}
```

You would obviously need to create three different images, one for each size and of course.

You could help speed up their download times by compressing them a little further. Try an online service such as https://kraken.io, even if you've saved for web in photoshop you can always squeeze a little more out of them.

Further to this you could make use of [Google's page speed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) which will give you pointers as to where you're site is winning and where it can be improved in terms of page speed